# Nginx Brotli dlopen failed (libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, dockerfile, dlopen, brotli, ngx-brotli

Error:

```
nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so" failed (/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:7
```

[Nginx Brotli dlopen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrDN8.png)

Dockerfile:

```
ARG version=1.23.2

FROM nginx:${version}-alpine AS builder

ARG version

WORKDIR /root/

RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base git pcre-dev openssl-dev zlib-dev linux-headers \
    && wget "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${version}.tar.gz" \
    && tar zxf nginx-${version}.tar.gz \
    && git clone https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli.git \
    && cd ngx_brotli \
    && git submodule update --init --recursive \
    && cd ../nginx-${version} \
    && ./configure \
    --add-dynamic-module=../ngx_brotli \
    --prefix=/etc/nginx \
    --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
    --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
    --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
    --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
    --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
    --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
    --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
    --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
    --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
    --with-perl_modules_path=/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl \
    --user=nginx \
    --group=nginx \
    --with-compat \
    --with-file-aio \
    --with-threads \
    --with-http_addition_module \
    --with-http_auth_request_module \
    --with-http_dav_module \
    --with-http_flv_module \
    --with-http_gunzip_module \
    --with-http_gzip_static_module \
    --with-http_mp4_module \
    --with-http_random_index_module \
    --with-http_realip_module \
    --with-http_secure_link_module \
    --with-http_slice_module \
    --with-http_ssl_module \
    --with-http_stub_status_module \
    --with-http_sub_module \
    --with-http_v2_module \
    --with-mail \
    --with-mail_ssl_module \
    --with-stream \
    --with-stream_realip_module \
    --with-stream_ssl_module \
    --with-stream_ssl_preread_module \
    --with-cc-opt='-Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g' \
    --with-ld-opt=-Wl,--as-needed,-O1,--sort-common \
    && make modules

FROM nginx:mainline-perl

ARG version

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --from=builder /root/nginx-${version}/objs/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/
COPY --from=builder /root/nginx-${version}/objs/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/

# Overwrite default conf file
COPY ./server/nginx-config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

EXPOSE 80 443
```

Related Questions:
1. https://serverfault.com/questions/1098295/cant-start-nginx-brotli-configuration-error
2. [Error while using Nginx lua module: libluajit-5.1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437633/error-while-using-nginx-lua-module-libluajit-5-1-so-2-cannot-open-shared-objec)
3. [Problem with brotli configuration in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067094/problem-with-brotli-configuration-in-nginx)

I'm trying to create a nginx enviroment with brotli compression, however I'm not sure why the container failed to start when I want load brotli module. May I know how can I solve this issue?

I have tested using full path or relative path in nginx.conf, both also not workings.

Comment: What is the output from `file -L /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so` ? Also please don't show _pictures_ of text -- they can't be cut/pasted from.

Comment: @EmployedRussian here is the result
/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so: cannot open `/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so' (No such file or directory).
Sure, I will paste the error in the question, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Well, the file you are trying to open doesn't exist, so what did you expect? (It could be a dead symlink).